# How to resolve error when read system call returns EIO on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive

I have a file that was created by some other program (MySQL), but when MySQL starts up, it fails. So I make a `strace` on the start procedure and I see the following error:

```
read(3, 0x1310000, 32768)               = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

As you can see, it returns -1 as error code and EIO as the errno. So I think it is a hardware failure (disk sector bad?); am I right? If so, how can I detect the problem? I have used smartctl and it tells HEATH. By the way, the filesystem is ext4.